# How do you convert imdb id's into tmdb id's?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, imdb

I need to convert IMDb ids into TMDB ids. Can someone please help me?
I have to manually find out all the ids and I have more than 4K movies.

Comment: Hey there, I would like you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and go through [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make the necessary changes. Its always a good practice to show your research and work so far related to the question as opposed to asking the community to write the code based on your requirement.

Comment: I hesitate to ask but... are you a member of TMDB and have you registered for an API key?

Comment: Have you read the TMDB support comment on [How can I get the TMDB Id using the imdb Id?](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/5f6a0500688cd000351c1712)